# Visual Studio Code JSX in JS Formatting Poorly on Save

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code I am trying to write JSX inside of a .js file, which is fine. However, when I go to save the file VSC poorly formats the code in the file since it doesn't seem to understand there is JSX inside the file. Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image: Pre-Save]

[image: Post-Save]

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed? Beautify and some other extensions have caused similar issues in the past

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem, as I had the "JS-CSS-HTML Formatter" VS Code extension installed.

There are three possibilities here: 
 1. Disabling the plugin.
 2. Uninstalling the plugin.
 3. Change the helped. "onSave" property in its config file. Press F1, then type "formatter" and choose "Formatter Config". change the "onSave" property to false and then (important) reload VS Code.

I used the 3rd option myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mac, got to *Preferences->Settings* and change your user settings or workspace settings as bellow. Remember to restart your VS Code application to reflect the changes.

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
    "files.associations": {
        "*.js": "javascriptreact"
    }
}
```